# look of webpages in awesomium

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, awesomium

I've created a wpf web browser with awesomium but the webpages do not look as clear as they are in chrome and others.I used visual c#.can some one help me with this?

Comment: Could you clarify what "do not look as clear" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the 1.6 branch, for better compositing against transparent backgrounds, we used Skia for font glyph rendering. The issue with this is that the hinting defaults to "smooth" which may seem "fuzzier" than fonts rendered with GDI.

Within the 1.7 branch, on Windows, we now use GDI/Cleartype (just like Chrome and IE) for most font rendering.

Comment: when is the official launch of 1.7.0?

Comment: there is no download event in the 1.7RC2.How do i handle downloads? @Adam

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do. We had the exact problem. Fonts in awesomium are a lot less readable than in Chrome or IE.

The bottom line is, if your application is gonna sell content, DO NOT USE AWESOMIUM!

Comment: OK good point to consider. But can you suggest some alternate options to use other than awesomium , that supports web page rendering and interaction with web pages like javascript execution etc

Comment: @JMat: My post  is a little old. Maybe Awesomium is now better, surely they've improved. The two top choices are either CefSharp or Awesomium. Just download them, validate them against your needs, and see which is more feasible, considering support, font outlook, price, etc..